# How to return the length of a line?

Tags: c

For example, lets say you asked the user to input their favorite word and scan it. How would you be able to return the length of that word on Eclipse? I came up with something like this and its not complete. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int getLineLength(int *linelength_ptr);

int main(void)
{
char faveword[50];
printf("Enter your favorite word.")
scanf("%50s", &faveword[0]);
}

int getLineLength(int *linelength_ptr);
```

Comment: You wrote c# and java tags, however it seems C language.

Comment: Have tried saving the line in a string and returnig the strings length in getLineLength function?

Comment: where is something part you tried ?? just function declaration ??

Answer (score 1):

Try using the strlen() function:

```
/* strlen example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char szInput[256];
  printf ("Enter a sentence: ");
  gets (szInput);
  printf ("The sentence entered is %u characters long.\n",(unsigned)strlen(szInput));
  return 0;
}
```

Taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/

Comment: Please don't recommend that people, especially beginners, use `gets()`. It should *never* be used. Use `fgets(szInput, sizeof szInput, stdin);` instead, it's much safer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: I wrote this answer before the OP removed the java tag, will leave it as a reference**

So if you want to accomplish this in JAVA, just use Scanner to get input and the .length() function:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a word or phrase");
String phrase = scan.next();
int wordLength = phrase.length();
```

where wordLength is an integer containing the length of the user input

Answer (score 0):

To enhance Phillip Ngan's answer: if you want to know how the `strlen` works fucntion, here is an inmplementation of your `getLineLength` function :

```
int getLineLength(char *string);
{
  int length = 0 ;
  while (*string++)
    length++ ;

  return length ;  
}
```

BTW: `getLineLength` must take an `char*` argument because a string actually an array of `char` terminated by a zero.